# STM32 SPI synchronization issue

Tags: c, stm32, spi, stm32f4, cubemx

I'm getting some really strange behavior on an STM32F429, trying to synchronize data over SPI with another microcontroller. The STM32F4 is SPI slave. I've been trying to simplify my code down to a minimal example, so for right now, I'm sending one byte at a time, receiving on the STM32F4 with a blocking function, and printing it via UART to see what it received.

<s>I have an additional GPIO pin that I assert prior to starting an SPI transaction, which is connected to an EXTI pin in order to make sure the STM32F4 is interrupted before the start of the SPI message.</s> I've removed all other application code, so this is the only thing in my code.

The problem is that if I send some particular values through, then SPI loses synchronization (0x44 causes it fairly repeatably, but other values have caused the issue).

For instance, if I send a string through from the master, along with an incrementing value:

```
...
0x40 Hello world
0x41 Hello world
0x42 Hello world
0x43 Hello world
0x44 Hello World
0x45 Hello World
...
```

on the receive side, it prints out:

```
@ Hello world
A Hello world
B Hello world
C Hello world
// and then  loses synchronization and prints:
  ((* "*"(
  ((* "*"(
```

It works successfully for arbitrarily long, and then fails when I send 0x44. Here is the relevant code (everything else is auto generated by CubeMX and essentially the default configuration).

```
uint8_t rx_buffer = 0;

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){
  if(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi5) == HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi5, &rx_buffer, 1, 500);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &rx_buffer, 1, 10);
  }
  rx_buffer = 0;
}

/**
  * @brief SPI5 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI5_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 1 */
  /* SPI5 parameter configuration*/
  hspi5.Instance = SPI5;
  hspi5.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi5.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi5.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
  hspi5.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi5.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI5_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI5_Init 2 */

}
```

I've slowed down SPI as much as I can from the master (I've used multiple microcontrollers as master, and all have issue, but I'm currently using a Cypress dev board), so it's running at 500kHz. I tried all permutations of CPOL and CPHA settings. Resetting the STM32F4 fixes it until I send another 0x44 value, so I don't think it has anything to do with the master device. I've tried making the EXTI interrupt highest priority, removed all other interrupt sources, taken out all my other application code, removed external interrupts entirely and polled the SPI state in the main loop. I've added delays to the master device, to make sure the slave has enough time to receive and process, as well as adjusting the timeout values in the HAL_SPI_Receive function. I also tried changing:

```
if(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi5) == HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)
```

to a blocking while loop:

```
while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi5) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)
  ;
```

I'm really at a loss here and I don't know what else to try.

Thanks,
Paul

edit:
Here is GPIO config. PF10 is my EXTI:

```
/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, NCS_MEMS_SPI_Pin|GPIO_PIN_2|OTG_FS_PSO_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, RDX_Pin|WRX_DCX_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, LD3_Pin|LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : A0_Pin A1_Pin A2_Pin A3_Pin 
                           A4_Pin A5_Pin SDNRAS_Pin A6_Pin 
                           A7_Pin A8_Pin A9_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = A0_Pin|A1_Pin|A2_Pin|A3_Pin 
                          |A4_Pin|A5_Pin|SDNRAS_Pin|A6_Pin 
                          |A7_Pin|A8_Pin|A9_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PF10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : SDNWE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SDNWE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(SDNWE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : NCS_MEMS_SPI_Pin PC2 OTG_FS_PSO_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = NCS_MEMS_SPI_Pin|GPIO_PIN_2|OTG_FS_PSO_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : B1_Pin MEMS_INT1_Pin MEMS_INT2_Pin TP_INT1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin|MEMS_INT1_Pin|MEMS_INT2_Pin|TP_INT1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : B5_Pin R4_Pin R5_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B5_Pin|R4_Pin|R5_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA4 PA6 PA7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_OC_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_OC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_OC_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : R3_Pin R6_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = R3_Pin|R6_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : BOOT1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BOOT1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(BOOT1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : A10_Pin A11_Pin BA0_Pin BA1_Pin 
                           SDCLK_Pin SDNCAS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = A10_Pin|A11_Pin|BA0_Pin|BA1_Pin 
                          |SDCLK_Pin|SDNCAS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : D4_Pin D5_Pin D6_Pin D7_Pin 
                           D8_Pin D9_Pin D10_Pin D11_Pin 
                           D12_Pin NBL0_Pin NBL1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = D4_Pin|D5_Pin|D6_Pin|D7_Pin 
                          |D8_Pin|D9_Pin|D10_Pin|D11_Pin 
                          |D12_Pin|NBL0_Pin|NBL1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : G4_Pin G5_Pin B6_Pin B7_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = G4_Pin|G5_Pin|B6_Pin|B7_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : OTG_HS_ID_Pin OTG_HS_DM_Pin OTG_HS_DP_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_HS_ID_Pin|OTG_HS_DM_Pin|OTG_HS_DP_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_OTG_HS_FS;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : VBUS_HS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VBUS_HS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(VBUS_HS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : D13_Pin D14_Pin D15_Pin D0_Pin 
                           D1_Pin D2_Pin D3_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = D13_Pin|D14_Pin|D15_Pin|D0_Pin 
                          |D1_Pin|D2_Pin|D3_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : TE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = TE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(TE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : RDX_Pin WRX_DCX_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RDX_Pin|WRX_DCX_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : R7_Pin DOTCLK_Pin B3_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = R7_Pin|DOTCLK_Pin|B3_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : HSYNC_Pin G6_Pin R2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = HSYNC_Pin|G6_Pin|R2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : I2C3_SDA_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2C3_SDA_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C3_SDA_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : I2C3_SCL_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2C3_SCL_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(I2C3_SCL_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : G7_Pin B2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = G7_Pin|B2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : G3_Pin B4_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = G3_Pin|B4_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_LTDC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD3_Pin LD4_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD3_Pin|LD4_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : SDCKE1_Pin SDNE1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SDCKE1_Pin|SDNE1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

}
```

edit2: Here is the polling version, updated to remove calling HAL_SPI_Receive from within ISR. Has the same problem.

```
int main(void)
{
/* initialization stuff */

  while(1)
  {
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi5, &rx_buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &rx_buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    // ----------------------------------------------------
    /* I've also instead tried to use NSS software mode and 
    manually checked NSS pin state

    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_6) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
      HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi5, &rx_buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &rx_buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    }
    */
  }
```

Comment: `SPI_NSS_HARD_*` never worked for me. I even started to believe we have found broken chips that set the NSS too late or too early when SPI transmission occured, so the other side couldn't get it right when the transmission started. It may take some rewritting, but try `SPI_NSS_SOFT` and detect the NSS using plain HAL_GPIO* functions. It also looks like you are missing `hspi5.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = something`

Comment: Whoa, you can't call `HAL_SPI_Receive` from inside an interrupt handler. You can, but it most probably will not work. In an interrupt handler just set a single `bool` flag or similar, and then inside `main` loop check the flag and execute some action to receive the transmission. The interrupt handling should be kept as small as possible. Depending on you uart speed `10)` looks small - I prefer to use `HAL_MAX_DELAY` for testing. Also, post the code how do you configure your gpio. Do you set `NSS_HARD` and at the same time use gpio interrupt on the same pin?

Comment: BaudRatePrescaler is only for master mode, isn't it? Initially, I set a flag in the ISR like you suggested, but the effect is the same. My intention was to call it from the ISR so that it blocks until SPI is done transmitting. But I also disabled all interrupts and polled HAL_SPI_Receive in the main loop anyway and it has the same problem. Regarding GPIO, I'm using a separate EXTI pin, independent from NSS.

Comment: Normally I work with MSP430/MSP432 controller, so I might talk nonsense. My idea: Do you trigger the EXTI pin for every character you send?  Then the interrupt can occur if sending over UART is not complete.  (It depends on the program on the sender MCU. (which I don't know) ). This could destroy the normal sync. Try to set off global interrupts when entering the Callback function and enable them when its left.  Due to missing interrupts there might be characters missing, but the pattern should vanish. It's not a solution, just to find out what happens.

Comment: Second idea: The output you showed, is not random, it has a pattern `((* "*"(`.  Are you sure, that the sender program doesn't fail and start sending this pattern?

Comment: Last but not least:  Do ST32F MCU allow SPI interrupts? I think so. Is there a reason, why you can not use them? Using an external interrupt to synchronize communication is not necessary if the MCU allows an inherent synchronization.

Comment: 1) It's a good idea, but I believe this is not the case because I've added huge delays before sending another byte from the master, like 1 sec delay, then send byte, wait another sec, etc.  I'll look into this again to double check. 2) The error pattern is "hello world" shifted by some number of bits, like it's missing one bit and then storing the byte starting from an offset. Resetting only the slave device resumes valid data transmission, so it can't be the master.

Comment: 3) I'll take another look at this. It's gone through many iterations, and I was trying to use SPI interrupts naively at first, with stm32's HAL_SPI_Receive_IT function and handling data in an SPI interrupt service routine. As the other commenter pointed out, NSS seems to be pretty unreliable on this platform, and so I was missing lots of data with this approach due to interrupts not firing at all, etc.

Comment: @PaulMusgrave did you find solution?

Comment: @Alatriste Unfortunately, no I never did. In my application, I switched to a UART.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to initialize SPI second time after some delay (100ms)
I had problem on stm32F105 - not all the time but most of the time SPI data was one bit shifted. I did not investigate it further, second initalization fixed it. Probably bad initialization order or not waiting on something.